# Graphql prisma string replace

Tags: graphql, prisma-graphql, typegraphql

I have graphql prisma api. Currently there is lyric field in Track table.

"Let it [Am]be, let it [C/G]be, let it [F]be, let it [C]be"

if I search using contain in graphql like example "Let it be", this record is not come out because of the chord. Is there a way to replace the chord in lyric field before searching with contain.

I even tried to use prisma, but I don't find a way to replace string.

Regards,
Alex

Comment: Have you looked the full text feature up?
https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/full-text-search

Comment: @Enfieldli I think it is not related with fulltext search. It is becasue of [Am] . If I take out [Am] and then search with "Let it be", this record come out. Is it related with fulltext search?

Comment: Do you wanna update the data before searching? Or just search without mutating db data?

Comment: just search without mutating db. Btw, I am also testing fulltext search and will let you know if it is working

Comment: Well, I think you can achieve that by using native search with regex, write raw sql with this api: https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/raw-database-access